# ASP MVC - Determine if a model bound parameter is null or just not passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In ASP MVC Web API, if I have a model class like this:

```
class UpdateModel
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public Date date { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

and a method like this:

```
public object Update(UpdateModel m)
{
    // update the object in the database according to the passed model
}
```

If the user posts a JSON object like { "type": "banana" } and omits name, how can I tell that the user is trying to update the type but they don't want to update the name at all? Versus if they pass { "name": null, "type": "banana" } which would indicate they want to update the name and they want it to be null because inside the Update() method, the model looks the same.

Comment: Why not handle null as do not update and string.empty ("") as update with empty name?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/clean-up-your-web-api-controllers-with-model-validation-and-null-check-filters/

Comment: Because then how do you differentiate between do not update and set to "" and set to null?

Comment: Yes I did check that link and it validates a model is passed but does help in deciding if a nullable property as passed.

Comment: You need to apply your own rules to this instead of assuming what the user is trying to persist. If the name property comes back null, then assume they do not want to update it or require the entire model to be sent. Like @RicoSuter stated, that seems to be the best solution if you do not require the entire model to be passed. If the entire model is passed, then you would know if the name property changed or not. You need a reference either on the server or coming from the client to know the user's intention.